# r plotting function questions

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a data array, `a`, shown below:

```
a <- structure(c(0.9984951, 0.9959022, 0.9888077, 0.9691369, 0.9110772, 
0.001501177, 0.004070025, 0.010984665, 0.029266702, 0.075221083, 
0.999987, 0.9999417, 0.9997387, 0.9988276, 0.9947208, 1.300713e-05, 
5.829127e-05, 0.0002611903, 0.001169507, 0.005219817, 0.9999757, 
0.9999152, 0.9997039, 0.9989658, 0.996382, 2.430024e-05, 8.481104e-05, 
0.0002959571, 0.001032229, 0.003593514), .Dim = c(5L, 2L, 3L))

dim(a)
[1] 5 2 3

a
, , 1
          [,1]        [,2]
[1,] 0.9984951 0.001501177
[2,] 0.9959022 0.004070025
[3,] 0.9888077 0.010984665
[4,] 0.9691369 0.029266702
[5,] 0.9110772 0.075221083

, , 2

          [,1]         [,2]
[1,] 0.9999870 1.300713e-05
[2,] 0.9999417 5.829127e-05
[3,] 0.9997387 2.611903e-04
[4,] 0.9988276 1.169507e-03
[5,] 0.9947208 5.219817e-03

, , 3

          [,1]         [,2]
[1,] 0.9999757 2.430024e-05
[2,] 0.9999152 8.481104e-05
[3,] 0.9997039 2.959571e-04
[4,] 0.9989658 1.032229e-03
[5,] 0.9963820 3.593514e-03
```

I have another vector that is the same length as the first dimension of the data array:

```
b = c(-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1)
```

Is there a way in r to plot the data so that I can get 3 separate plots (this number equals the third dimensions of the array and each plot has 2 lines on it (this number equals the second dimensions of the array). And each line is the second dimension values as the y axis and the vector b as the x-axis, so the first data block should be the first plot, and two columns indicate two lines, and each column is the y values, and the corresponding x values are included in the b vector. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What are the dimensions of `a` (`dim(a)`)? It look's like your subsetting `a` with `a[5, 2, 3]`, but the output looks like it could be `print(a)`.

Comment: oh the output is print(a), so the dim(a) is c(5, 2, 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for a `ggplot` solution, let's go all in with Tidyverse.

First, let's convert our 3 dimensional array into a list of data.frames:

```
my.dfs <- apply(a,3,as.data.frame)
```

Data frame columns must be named in R, so they will get the defaults of `c("V1","V2")`. You could set them to something differently in the `apply` call if you wanted.

Now let's use `purrr::map2` to bind together the data from the array, together with a plot number and your `b` vector

```
library(tidyvers)
data <- map2_dfr(my.dfs,seq_along(my.dfs),~cbind(.x,plot = .y, b))
```

For plotting, we'll need to pivot the data into long form:

```
data <- pivot_longer(data, -c(plot,b), names_to = "variable")
```

And finally we can use the `col =`  asethetic to change the line color by variable and use `facet_wrap` to make multiple plots.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = b, y = value, col = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~plot)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should consider:

```
d <- dim(a)
data.frame( x = b, y = c(a), plots = gl(d[3], prod(d[-3])), cols = gl(d[2], d[1])) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x, y, col = cols)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(~plots)
```

[image]